# How can i find hardcoded(?!) Store Mail

Tags: email, magento-1.8.1.0

The Store is defined under magentoA.com but the Store Mails (Newsletter, orders, etc) is on shop@developer.com - i think i don't have to say that this is a pity.

So even if i change the store mails it doesn't change - i think these mails are hardcoded?

May someone can give me a hint -

mailq (@debian sys) is showing me that something is sent by this shop@developer.com (www-data) may this gives someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Admin > System > Configuration > Store Email Addresses` look here, check all store scopes, set them to desired email.

You may also want to double check `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Mail Sending Settings` and/or attempt to determine wether or not you're using an extension that offloads mail sending to something other than your localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. sadly i already tried this point . The store still sends via the shop@developer.com Adress as stated above.

Comment: Have you tried to grep -r shop@developer.com from your project root? Also, I would try running `php -i | grep shop@developer.com` from the server's shell to see if your sendmail path has the from email set to this address. Also added an alternative place to look in my answer.

Comment: under var/www/
grep -r -i 'shop@developer.com' ./

=> not successfull

php did the same.

Comment: Flush cache? The settings are read out of `core_config_data` and cached. Won't change till cache is flushed. Might have to manually delete the mage folders under var/cache/.